# How can I write doctests with flask-sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy, doctest

My application works. Only the doctests don't work.

In the application, I use a pattern

```
from models import db

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = "mysql://..."

db.init_app(app)

...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', threaded=True)
```

I have a couple of really simple doctests. Before switching from Flask + Sqlalchemy to flask-sqlalchemy, it worked:

```
>>> import database
>>> files_insert(..., no_commit=True)  # database stuff happens here
>>> database.session.rollback()
```

It's ok to remove the insert tests (they probably didn't make too much sense anyway), but I have a couple of functions which only need to select elements from the database. That should definitely still work. But I get:

```
RuntimeError: application not registered on db instance and no applicationbound to current context
```

Is there a way to configure my app so that docstrings always get the application context?

Answer (score 1):

You doctest is missing an app context and since you use flask-sqlalchemy you have bound the app instance and the DB instance.Check [this issue](https://github.com/pallets/flask/issues/1680).

A workaround (A hack really) is to patch  flask session, request, and current_app objects, look at [this comment on the same issue](https://github.com/pallets/flask/issues/1680#issuecomment-213441736) which patch it for `pytest`.

But IMHO when you start hacking this way, it's time to switch to a regular test method, unittest or pytest.

While `doctest` is nice for simple code when you have to hack and/or setup a complete context to run a doctest, you lose the simplicity of it anyway...